# Facing issue installing oracle in windows with the command npm install oracle

Tags: node.js, oracle

[image]

My machine having oracle 11g. Receiving the attached error, while installing oracle. Appreciated if someone helps me on this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have an appropriate build environment installed to compile the `oracle` addon. On Windows, it *should* be as simple as doing: [`npm install -g windows-build-tools`](https://github.com/felixrieseberg/windows-build-tools). That will fetch and install Python, the VC++ compiler, and related build tools.

Comment: receving the following error D:\nodeapp>npm install -g window-build-tools
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "window-build-tool
npm ERR! node v6.9.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8
npm ERR! code E404

Comment: It's `windows-build-tools` *not* `window-build-tools` or `window-build-tool`.